# Consulta C# a SQLITE

Tags: c#, sqlite, sqlite3

Tengo la siguiente Base de Datos

```
CREATE TABLE [Request] (
[IDRequest] INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
[RequestID] VARCHAR(10)  NULL,
[ReceivedDate] VARCHAR(20)  NULL,
[RequestStatus] VARCHAR(20)  NULL,
[ExpirationStatus] VARCHAR(15)  NULL,
[ResponseStatus] VARCHAR(20)  NULL,
[StatusMessage] VARCHAR(20)  NULL
)
```

Para conectarme utilizo lo siguiente

```
private SQLiteConnection conexionBD;
        

        public DAOConexion (string directorio)
        {
            this.conexionBD = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=" + directorio + ";Version=3;");
        }

        
        public void Conectar()
        {
            conexionBD.Open();
        }

        public bool doInsert(string sql)
        {
            //Creo y corro la consulta
            SQLiteCommand sqlcommand = new SQLiteCommand(sql, conexionBD);

            if (sqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery() > 1)
            {
                sqlcommand.Dispose();
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                sqlcommand.Dispose();
                return true;
            }
        }
```

La implementacion que estoy usando a modo prueba es la siguiente

```
conBD.doInsert ("INSERT INTO Request (RequestID, ReceivedDate, RequestStatus, ExpirationStatus ,ResponseStatus, StatusMessage)VALUES ('1', 'asd', '32', 'California', '20000.00','sadsa' );");
```

El problema es que me esta arrojando

> SQLite error
>
> no such table: Request

La tabla esta creada y si utilizo la misma consulta en la base funciona.

Comment: Era un error de la DDL, la cambie y funciono

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Era un error de DLL, la solución fue bajar otra versión de la DLL e insertarla en el proyecto

Comment: Probaste con insertar mediante metodos? conexionBD.Insert(Objeto);

Answer (score 0):

Verifica el esquema, puede que este consultado en otro esquema, prueba:

**INSERT INTO NOMBRE_DB.Request...**